# Equivalence of matrix multiplication with order changed

Tags: matrices

I know that, for square matrices, $AB = B^{t}A^{t}$.
But I'm looking for a $AB$ equivalent multiplication in witch $A$ stay non-alternated.

Is there some modification I can do in $B$ to get $AB = B^{'}A$?

Comment: Try dividing both sides by $A$ to solve for  $B'$.

Comment: You don't know that $AB = B^t A^t$, unless you know $AB$ is symmetric.

Comment: Good evaluation @RobertIsrael, I'll complement the question description